# Yaml templates in Kubernetes

Tags: yaml, kubernetes

Where can I find an official template which describes how to create your `.yaml` file to setup services/pods in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the specification for a pod here http://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions/#_v1_pod

A good starting point is also the examples https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples

Additional you can create the ressource via kubectl and export the resource to yaml

e.g. for a pod you can run this command:

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx 
 kubectl get pods ngnix -o yaml > pod.yaml`

Comment: can I just create a pod, service etc with the oc command and use the deploymentconfig as template for a next time?

Comment: You can do this with kubectl. For pod e.g. ```kubectl run nginx --image=nginx``` and ```kubectl get pods ngnix -o yaml > pod.yaml```